# The use of the word “exposed” in acts 7:19 and Hebrews 4:13

Tags: greek, hebrew, acts

Is the use of the word “exposed” in Acts 7:19 the same as the one used in Hebrews 4:13, when referencing the word of God?

> **Acts 7:19 [ESV]** He dealt shrewdly with our race and forced our fathers to **expose** their infants, so that they would not be kept alive.ESV

> **Hebrews 4:13 [ESV]** And no creature is hidden from his sight, but all are naked and **exposed** to the eyes of him to whom we must give account.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Could you please edit so as to quote the text you are referencing, citing the version,  so that we know the wording in detail and in context.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the site tour (hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on how this site is a little different than other sites around the web: hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/… Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

English Standard Version Acts 7:19

> He dealt shrewdly with our race and forced our fathers to **expose** their infants, so that they would not be kept alive.

https://biblehub.com/acts/7-19.htm
to **abandon**
ἔκθετα (ektheta)
Adjective - Accusative Neuter Plural
Strong's Greek 1570: Cast out, **exposed (to the elements)**, abandoned. From **ek** and a derivative of tithemi; put out, i.e. Exposed to perish.

New International Version translated it quite differently:

> He dealt treacherously with our people and oppressed our ancestors by forcing them to **throw out** their newborn babies so that they would die.

Now about the other verse in
Hebrews 4:13

> And no creature is hidden from his sight, but all are naked and **exposed** to the eyes of him to whom we must give account.

exposed
τετραχηλισμένα (tetrachēlismena)
Verb - Perfect Participle Middle or Passive - Nominative Neuter Plural
Strong's Greek 5136: To be laid bare, **laid open**. From trachelos; to seize by the throat or neck, i.e. To expose the gullet of a victim for killing.

New International Version translated it differently:

> Nothing in all creation is hidden from God's sight. Everything is uncovered and **laid bare** before the eyes of him to whom we must give account.

Is the use of the word “exposed” in Acts 7:19 the same as the one used in Hebrews 4:13, when referencing the word of God?

No, they are two different Greek words that got translated by ESV as "exposed".
The two Greek words even have different Greek roots with different pragmatic usages.